# zip function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, implementation

implementation of a zip function that takes two lists as parameters and returns a new list of pairs. I got this so far

```
myZip [] [] = []
myZip (x:xs) (y:ys) = [(x,y)] ++ myZip xs ys
```

any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's really only one way to write it for lists, even for homework:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b) : zip as bs
zip _      _      = []
```

or, more generally,

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a]->[b]->[c]
zipWith f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : zipWith f as bs
zipWith _ _      _      = []
```

---

If you want to get wacky, and play with stream fusion, the version from the stream fusion paper, in automaton style,

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> Stream a -> Stream b -> Stream c
zipWith f (Stream next0 sa0) (Stream next1 sb0) = Stream next (sa0, sb0, Nothing)
  where
    next (sa, sb, Nothing) = case next0 sa of
        Done        -> Done
        Skip    sa' -> Skip (sa', sb, Nothing)
        Yield a sa' -> Skip (sa', sb, Just a)

    next (sa', sb, Just a) = case next1 sb of
        Done        -> Done
        Skip    sb' -> Skip          (sa', sb', Just a)
        Yield b sb' -> Yield (f a b) (sa', sb', Nothing)
```

Comment: is there a difference between using ':' and '++' ?

Comment: Yes, `(++)` is list append, and traverses its first argument, while `(:)` is O(1), and prepends its argument to the list.

Comment: @biz, and there's the subtle, but important, difference that `:` is a data constructor, while `++` is just an ordinary function. That means you can use `:` when pattern matching, but you can't use `++`. Take a look in ghci with `:i (:)` and `:i (++)`.

Comment: In this case, however, there should be no difference between using `(a,b) : ...` and `[(a,b)] ++ ...`.  The former is simpler and more idiomatic, but the semantics and performance should be identical (the compiler will just unfold the latter to the former)

Comment: This answer implements zip, but does not critique the asker's version or explain why it is implemented the way it is.  Could be better.

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps we could link to the general answers on `(++)` and `(:)`

Comment: By the way, GHC does literally optimize them both to the same code, thanks to `build/foldr` rules.

Comment: 'f a b' ?? don't get it